# Where is the JSON schema for Slack Block Kit?

Tags: slack, jsonschema, slack-api

The [block kit builder (slack.com)](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/) is able to validate json input, so the schema is available somewhere :

But the [schema (github.com)](https://github.com/slackapi/slack-api-specs/blob/master/web-api/slack_web_openapi_v2_without_examples.json) I found in Slack docs has no definitions for the blocks:

```
        "blocks": {
        "description": "This is a very loose definition, in the future, we'll populate this with deeper schema in this definition namespace.",
        "items": {
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "type"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        },
        "title": "Block Kit blocks",
        "type": "array"
    },
```

So, is this available anywhere ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that block schema is available anywhere right now. There is a pending [issue](https://github.com/slackapi/slack-api-specs/issues/18) on Slack's github repo that speaks about exactly the same problem. The last official response was sent more than a year ago.

Comment: Gosh I will have to extract the validation code from the block kit builder then

Comment: I wish it was present on the client-side. For validation, the block kit builder seems to be making a request to `/api/blocks.format` endpoint. This endpoint compares the payload with the schema and returns errors if any.

Comment: Ah! thats is a bummer. But thank you anyway @JaiPandya :)

Comment: It looks like it was available for a while months ago (see my answer) and someone extracted it. I couldn't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Someone found the JSON schema a while ago using browser developer console and shared it online. As far as I have just tested, it is not available anymore.

See https://gist.github.com/renatorib/1fb1a9bd71435b41bee602d15bc56899

It would be great if Slack team shares it officially or add it to OpenAPI specifications.